# Clone div and append it to body

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am having some trouble. I would like to take a div object in html, in this case the div with id "snowflake", clone it, and append it to itself (add the new snowflake to the end of the original so that I have two snowflakes now). With that, I would then like to be able to use math.random to adjust the positioning of the snowflake. How would I go about this? Eventually I want to create 100 snowflakes with random positioning. Please let me know a way I can do this WITHOUT jquery (purely javascript, css, and html). Thank you all!

**HTML**

```
 <body>
  <div id=body>
   <!-- Snowflake -->
   <div id="snowflake">
    <div class="snowflake-container">
      ...
    </div>
  </div>
  <!-- New snowflake should go here -->
 </div>
</body>
```

**JAVASCRIPT**

```
var snowflake = document.getElementById("snowflake");
var bodyDiv = document.getElementById("body");
var snowflakeContainer = document.createElement('div');
var snowflakeClone = snowflake.cloneNode(true);

bodyDiv.addEventListener("click", createSnowflake);

function createSnowflake() {
  console.log("click is working");
  bodyDiv.appendChild(snowflakeClone);
 }
```

This works but it only creates one snowflake clone. I would like to create one each time the page is clicked.

Comment: What have you tried? We don't just write up solutions here. We answer specific questions about specific problems.

Comment: And, just a couple of points: Why is the `snowflake-container` inside of the `snowflake`? And, if you want additional snowflakes to come after the first one, then they wouldn't be appended to the first one (as you state you want), they'd be appended to the `body`. You should re-think your HTML and exactly what you are trying to do.

Comment: I have tried using the cloneNode method on the snowflake and have tried to appendChild it to the body to no avail. I have tried to search for other solutions online but google is only coming up with .clone() methods for jquery which is not helpful for me.

Comment: So show us the code that you tried. Then, we can tell you where you went wrong.

Comment: Show us some code and explain what is this for. Maybe then we can suggest an easier way.

Comment: I think in this case it doesn't matter which container is named snowflake/snowflake container but in any case, I want to duplicate the container with id snowflake. Yes I would like to append the body with the snowflake. Sorry for that lapse in syntax and concentration.

Comment: It just sounds strange when you see a container INSIDE the contained object, don't you think? Sometimes the simple fact of naming things wrong make your thinking confused.

Comment: Ah i see. Well here is the code:

Comment: No. Don't add the code as a comment. Edit your question and add the code (formatted please) there.

Comment: Yes i just realized how silly that was. Edited the comment, if anything is wrong or messed up please let me know. I'm still new to stackoverflow.

Comment: Also I realized my title was completely off topic. I was going to ask something different but I thought I would go with this first, which is why. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's clear out the clutter and just deal with the essential parts of your problem.

```js
// Get a reference to the snow flake container
var snowflake = document.querySelector(".snowflake-container");

// Set up a click event handler for the document
document.addEventListener("click", createSnowflake);

function createSnowflake() {
  // Clone the first snow flake container and append the clone to the body
  document.body.appendChild(snowflake.cloneNode(true));
}
```

```css
#snowflake {
  user-select:none; /* Prevents user from selecting content */
  background-image:url("http://ci.snowflake.az.us/wp-content/uploads/2015/10/cropped-snowflake-only-logo.png");
  background-size:contain;
  width:50px;
  height:50px;
}
```

```html
<!-- The container should be the outermost element -->
<div class="snowflake-container">
  <div id="snowflake"></div>
</div>
```

Comment: Great thank you Scott. How would I go by creating more than one snowflake?

Comment: @MichaelMungai The answer already shows this. Just keep clicking.